# iPad popoverControl

Tags: ipad, uipopovercontroller

i have implemented the popover view to the BarButtonItem, it works and shows the popover but the arrow which is permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionDown - in this the arrow will show in the down direction.but it hides the bottom bar,can any one help me to over come this problem of hiding the barbutton..

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go with `UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny` .

Comment: i have tried that also but it shows the same issue.may i have any other options? :(

Comment: I'm not sure If I got your problem. Maybe you should post code+screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried that also but it did not work so I fixed the problem by fixing the HT & WT

Thanks